# How to stop visual studio 2013 hanging when loading a solution with a project from another solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs

the problem is thus.  Every time I open a specific solution in visual studio it hangs forever, you get the annoying Visual Studio is Busy popup.  The only way to get it to load is starting visual studio in safemode or by deleting the v12.suo file before opening the solution.

Once it's hung all the projects are marked (Initializing) apart from one project that is (loading).  This project is from a different solution and from a different place in the tfs tree.  If I unload the shared project then VS loads the solution fine, I think the problem is with TFS, can it deal with a project in multiple solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Opening another solutions projects is a pretty bad practice. Why not take a dependancy on the binary output and public PDB's?

Comment: @MrHinsh thanks, Would do if it were a project that can build, it's more a dumping ground for shared js, css, images.  It doesn't need to be in the solution except to be able to easily see that stuff and for deployment.

Comment: Sounds like that stuff should be chopped up into discreet components and shared using Nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the shared solution and instead share discreet components as Nuget Packages.

I would generally have a Solution & Project for each of my shared groups... Usually there is a relationship between the css, images, and JavaScript... And package each one as a Nuget Package. Add an automated release pipeline and you can have checkin->dependancy in very short order.

I use VSTS and have a Build that creates a Nuget package with the bits I need and then use the release management tools to control visibility and quality of that package. It's then easy to have your packages deployed to a Nuget Repository (I use VSTS) and let any of your internal projects take a dependancy on them.

This will have the added bonus of increasing quality and knowledge of dependancies and interfaces in your devs. Let them have a dumping ground and they will always use one.

Comment: Hi thanks, it was always the right thing to do and the annoyance of VS hanging forced me to do it.  well done MS for enforcing good practice through bugs

Answer (score 0):

You can do below steps  to narrow down this issue:

Try invoking Visual Studio from the command line `devenv.exe /log`. Then try to open your solution and then if it crashes, go look at the

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ActivityLog.xml
```

file. It will including some details on the crash. Also, the event logs may capture some high level events as well.

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried this and tried comparing the log generated when it opened successfully without the suo file.  Nothing of note.  debugging with another VS and getting the dump didn't help either.